# Can I render a 2D circle using mayavi?

Tags: python, mayavi

I'm using mayavi with python to show a collection of points, each of which has a 3D-coordinate, a color and a size.

Now I can use `points3D` to show them as 3D spheres. And I'm wondering whether I can render them as 2D circles which *always facing* the camera.

Comment: points3d accepts a mode argument. One option is, quite literally, "2dcircle"... http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#points3d (you may need additional options such as scale_factor to get it looking right)

Comment: @abought Yes, I did try it, but those circles are still 3D object which not always facing the camera.

Comment: What do you mean by "always facing the camera?"  A sphere has no concept of directionality -- if it were rotated 180 degrees along the depth axis it would still look like a sphere.

What I think you are asking for is to make all of the spheres be the same size regardless of how the user rotates the camera in 3D.  Another thing you might be asking, but which seems less likely, is how to set the camera such that it cannot be rotated.

Comment: @aestrivex I want mayavi to use a circle without shader to render a sphere, which can be faster and cleaner than real sphere.

Comment: Oh I see -- I'm not sure vtk will do that at all